# Are there connected sets $A,B,C$?

Tags: general-topology

Are there $A,B,C$ such that $A,B,C,A\cap B,A\cap C,B\cap C$ are connected but $A\cap B\cap C$ is not connected?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, for example two half-planes and one annulus:
\begin{align}
&A=\{(x,y)\in \mathbb R^2: x\geq-1\}\\
&B=\{(x,y)\in\mathbb R^2:x\leq 1\}\\
&C=\{(x,y)\in\mathbb R^2:4\leq x^2+y^2\leq 5\}
\end{align}